# How do I ensure same proportions in any type of screen size for imagebutton in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, responsive-design

I have an imagebutton which I want to have it the same proportion for any type of screen size, so I want to do adjust in size according to the screen size so the all the ratios are the same. I tried to find an answer to how to do this but I can't find anything that explains how to do it clearly. This is my current image view code in my xml file.

```
    <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/torchbtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

                android:background="@color/black"
                android:src="@drawable/torch_off">
            </ImageButton>
```

Comment: And what those proportions are supposed to be?

Comment: I haven't decided on that yet, I want to know the code, for example I want to set a png image which takes up 50% of the screen in width and height but I don't know how to

Comment: I can give you the answer for that example but the proportions are they key information for the answer that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `ConstraintLayout` there is somewhat easy and straightforward way how to do it.

One of the widgets added with `ConstraintLayout` is `Guideline` that has an option to set the "margin" in percentages. Given your example of the `ImageButton` occupying 50% of the space you can do it with 4 `Guideline`s.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/torchbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/torch_off"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/guideline_end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_start"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_top" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```